# Infinite Maven 'target/classes' folders

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, directory

I'm using Eclipse (Kepler) and the m2e Maven plugin for Eclipse.
I have a Maven project, but when I export the jar in Eclipse (as in right click project, export, jar, etc..), it creates a weird infinite or nearly infinite folder loop.

This is the Eclipse folder for that project (there's nothing wrong with it):
*PIC 1* (Pics link is at the end of the page, could not upload pics)

Now, when I go inside the target folder it's still all good: *PIC 2*

All is well as you can see.

However, when I navigate into the classes folder there is another 'target' folder that has another folder 'classes', which has 'target', and so on..

This is the view when you go into the classes folder from the last picture.
*PIC 3*

As you can see, it keeps on going. It's removable, but I used 'robocopy' with cmdprompt. It keeps on going back though.
*PIC 4*

**Pics:** http://pastebin.com/p1QiAVnE

What can I do to stop Eclipse from doing this?

**EDIT:** I should of course share my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Autorank</groupId>
<artifactId>Autorank</artifactId>
<version>3.4-Dev-${BUILD_NUMBER}</version>
<name>Autorank</name>
<description>Maven project for Bukkit plugin Autorank</description>
<url>http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/autorank/</url>
<build>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>

        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>


    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${basedir}/Javadocs</exclude>
                    <exclude>${basedir}/lib</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Stop Maven from including the dependencies (.jars) in the artifact 
            (created by Jenkins) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<properties> <!-- Fix encoding warnings -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>bukkit-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>Plugin Metrics</id>
        <url>http://repo.mcstats.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>stats-repo</id>
        <url>http://centrility.nl:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
        </url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>sk89q-repo</id>
        <url>http://maven.sk89q.com/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>Spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>staartvin-repo</id>
        <url>http://62.131.38.74:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.ess</groupId>
        <artifactId>Essentials</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>EssentialsGroupManager</groupId>
        <artifactId>EssentialsGroupManager</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.massivecraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>Factions</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.massivecraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>MassiveCore</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.platymuus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit-permissions</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.lolmewn.stats</groupId>
        <artifactId>Stats</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.milkbowl.vault</groupId>
        <artifactId>Vault</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
        <artifactId>worldedit</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mcstats.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics</artifactId>
        <version>R7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
        <artifactId>worldguard</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-beta-01</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gmail.nossr50.mcMMO</groupId>
        <artifactId>mcMMO</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.02</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>RoyalCommands</groupId>
        <artifactId>RoyalCommands</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>OnTime</groupId>
        <artifactId>OnTime</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>UltimateCore</groupId>
        <artifactId>UltimateCore</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>Statistics</groupId>
        <artifactId>Statistics</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9-R0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Would think you'll have to share the contents of your Maven POM. Also, when you say "export the jar in Eclipse", do you mean that you are using m2e within Eclipse to run the package goal on your Maven project or are you doing something else there?

Comment: Ok, I understand better now about what you mean when you say "export the jar"--not sure if the parenthetical comment was there before or not. It really looks like what you would be doing would just be creating a jar from what is on the filesystem. Have you examined the file system to see what's there before you take that export step? My guess is that the export jar operation as you describe it is not adding any structure--is that correct? I could be wrong and I know your question suggests that I am, but thought we should check this point.

Comment: @unigeek It seems to also happen when I'm just saving the project in Eclipse. So there is something wrong with Eclipse saving it.

Comment: Ok, so maybe the Maven POM is not the right place to be looking then. I would try to do a clean build (Project > Clean) on your project and then also look at settings like Project > Build Automatically (which might actually be doing the thing you perceive happens on save) and Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Building. Take a look at the output folders between making changes so you can get a handle on what is happening at each step.

Comment: @unigeek It's building automatically. I have not enabled project specific settings for the builder, so it's using the default output folders. I don't know what those are, because I can't find it anywhere. I think it's an issue with Maven as it only happens with this project (which is the only Maven project), and it constantly creates the 'target' folder.

Comment: I'd suggest you uncheck the build automatically option and do a project clean as above, such that you have no build artifacts. If you used m2e to import your maven project, your build artifacts should be delivered to <your project dir>/target/classes. If you created the project from scratch with Eclipse you need to assess the output directory from the Eclipse project properties (look under Java Build Path at the bottom of the "Source" tab). Then, when you know where you will look, use eclipse to build manually and then observe the filesystem for results. Does it make sense?

Comment: Okay, so I unchecked 'build automatically' and it cleaned the 'project/target/classes/' folder which good. I then clicked 'Build project' and it created the classes in the /project/target/classes/ folder and a META-INF folder (it's important to note that there is no 'target' folder inside the classes folder, so no 'endless loop' just yet). I edited a few classes inside Eclipse and saved them. Nothing changed. No 'target' folder appearing. I then clicked export, and after it exported the jar, the frustrating 'target' folder had been created. So the problem is occuring at export.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, infinite class/target/class/target directory. I had to use a freeware program called Long Path Eraser to delete those directories.

I will tell you what solved my problem, I changed this:

```
<include>**/*.yml</include>
```

To this:

```
 <include>filename.yml</include>
```

Instead of letting maven search for the files. Fortunately I only had one file so this was a valid solution for me. Perhaps it might help if you change yours to "directory/*.yml" instead of a wildcard directory.

Comment: This seems to work. I'll test it for a while and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Could be wrong here, but hopefully it's just a matter of drilling into the JAR Export dialog to expand your project and deselecting the target folder. It seems that the dialog box could be a little more obvious about what it will include in the jar file, but instead it (at least in my case) collapses the project and thus hides the detail of what will be included in the jar. See if you can find the checkbox shown here and export again with that box unchecked. Good luck!

[image: Eclipse's jar export dialog box]

Comment: @Staartvin any luck with this? I had the sense that you were on the right track from earlier discussion.

Comment: It seems not to create any 'target' folder when I do not select it. However, if I **do** select it, isn't doesn't create one either. However, the target folder appears randomly after a while, filled with the repeating folder pattern.